# MySQL запрос: либо инпуты , либо fieldset не в том порядке

Tags: база-данных, sql, mysql

Помогите пожалуйста построить запрос

Делаю конструктор форм.

Есть три таблицы (fields хранит возможные input'ы, fieldset - группу инпутов, field_type - возможные типы инпутов)

fields

- id
- field_type_id
- title
- required
- visibility
- values
- order
- belong
- fieldset_id
- tooltip

fieldset

- id
- title
- belong
- order

field_type

- id
- name

Хочется сделать выборку чтобы результат был такой:

- FIELSET 1
- input 1
- input 2
- input 3
- FIELSET 2
- input 4
- input 5
- input n (которые без fieldset)

Делаю следующий запрос

```
SELECT a.*, b.name AS field_name, c.id AS fieldset_id, c.title AS fieldset_title, c.order AS fieldset_order
                FROM fields a
                LEFT JOIN field_type b ON b.id = a.field_type_id
                LEFT JOIN fieldset c ON c.id = a.fieldset_id  
                WHERE a.belong = 'employer' ORDER BY a.order, fieldset_order
```

Получается отсортировать либо по fieldset order, либо по field order, в итоге инпуты идут не в том порядке, либо fieldset не в том порядке

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй через `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT fl.fieldset_id, 1, fl.title
FROM fields fl

UNION ALL

SELECT fs.id, 0, fs.title
FROM fieldset fs

ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

В коде показал только две колонки. Остальные - самостоятельно. В каждом запросе можно использовать все остальные конструкции типа `JOIN` и `WHERE`. Главное, при использовании `UNION` - должно совпадать кол-во колонок обоих запросов.

Сортировка относится ко всему результату.